# Backtracking, dado un numero X de caballos, Y reyes, N reinas y Z alfiles

Tags: javascript, java, recursión

El usuario puede elegir el número de piezas que desea colocar, el algoritmo debe encontrar una solución de tal manera que ninguna figura se mate entre sí. Es similar al de las N-reinas pero necesito alguna recomendación o ejemplos. Mas que nada porque de las N-reinas hay mucha información y ejemplos pero con diferentes figuras no he encontrado nada relevante. Mi implementación es en Java pero valoro igualmente ejemplos con otros lenguajes.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Poco te podemos ayudar si no compartes el código que has intentado...

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa. Te dejo los siguientes enlaces para que mejores tu pregunta. Evita los negativos e incluso el cierre de tu pregunta. [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/107347), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878/107347), [solicitas directamente que alguien haga tu trabajo/tarea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320/107347). De paso Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] tablero = { { " ", " ", " ", " " },  
                           { " ", " ", " ", " " }, 
                           { " ", " ", " ", " " },
                           { " ", " ", " ", " " } }; 
    boolean ward = true;  
    int tamañoTablero = 0;
    do {
        ward = true;
        try {
            tamañoTablero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño del tablero"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, el dato ingresado es inválido", "Error",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            ward = false;
        }
    } while (ward == false);
    tablero = generarTablero(tamañoTablero);  
    ubicarReina(tablero, 0);
}

public static void ubicarReina(String[][] tablero, int etapa) {

    for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
        if (isValido(tablero, i, etapa)) {
            tablero[i][etapa] = "D";  

            if (etapa < tablero.length - 1) {
                ubicarReina(tablero, etapa + 1);
            } else {
                imprimirMatriz(tablero);
                System.out.println("_______________________");
            }

            tablero[i][etapa] = " ";
        }

    }  
}    

public static boolean isValido(String[][] tablero, int i, int etapa) {

    for (int x = 0; x < etapa; x++) {
        if (tablero[i][x].equals("D")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < tablero.length && (i - j) >= 0 && (etapa - j) >= 0; j++) {

        if (tablero[i - j][etapa - j].equals("D")) {
            return false;
        }
    }  
    for (int j = 0; j < tablero.length && (i + j) < tablero.length && etapa - j >= 0; j++) {

        if (tablero[i + j][etapa - j].equals("D")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}

public static String[][] generarTablero(int length) {
    String[][] res = new String[length][length];
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
            res[i][j] = " ";
        }  
    }
    return res;
}

public static void imprimirMatriz(String[][] tablero) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tablero.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("  " + tablero[i][j] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```